# How to correctly expand several addresses into a table?

Tags: mysql

I have an example with 2 tables, one with orders and one with adresses. A order has an ID, a productnumber and 3 different addresses, one for the actual delivery, one for the billing and one for a "Thank you"-letter.

Now I am getting all columns based on its orderID (so I can later create an object in Java with it and use it further).

**Output:**

```
orderingsid productnumber   CustomerName    CustomerStreet  CustomerZip CustomerLocation    BillingName BillingStreet   BillingZip  BillingLocation ThankYouName    ThankYouStreet  ThankYouZip ThankYouLocation
    1           70              frank           "str a"         17              M               frank       "str a"         17          M               frank           "str a"         17          m           
    2           80              anton           "str b"         18              n               stefan      "str c"         19          o               stefan          "str c"         19          o           
    3           90              stefan          "str c"         19              o               tim         "str d"         20          p               alice           "str e"         21          q           
    4           100             tim             "str d"         20              p               frank       "str a"         17          M               tim             "str d"         20          p           
    5           110             alice           "str e"         21              q               anton       "str b"         18          n               anton           "str b"         18          n
```

For example in order 3 stefan got the delivery, while tim paid for it and alice got the thank-you letter since it was her idea to buy the product.

I am able to create the output with this MySQL statement:

```
select orderings.orderingsid, orderings.productnumber,
    delivery.customername as CustomerName,
    delivery.street as CustomerStreet,
    delivery.zipcode as CustomerZip,
    delivery.location as CustomerLocation,
    billing.customername as BillingName,
    billing.street as BillingStreet,
    billing.zipcode as BillingZip,
    billing.location as BillingLocation,
    thankyou.customername as ThankYouName,
    thankyou.street as ThankYouStreet,
    thankyou.zipcode as ThankYouZip,
    thankyou.location as ThankYouLocation
    from orderings
    join addresses as delivery on orderings.deliveryaddress = delivery.adressid
    join addresses as billing on orderings.billingaddress = billing.adressid
    join addresses as thankyou on orderings.thankyouletteradress = thankyou.adressid;
```

**My Question:**
I am not sure if this is the optimal way to do this. This is an example I have created for this SO-question, my real database is bigger and has 30-40 attributes per table. This makes the `select`-statement pretty bloated, as I have to chose all columns by hand and rename them (else I would have 3 columns named `street` which would be hard to deal with in Java).

I have thought about normalizing the database and create 3 new tables (deliverytable, billingtable, thankyoutable) where I separate the addresses into, but with my approach I only have to create 1 table. Also with 3 tables the column-naming would get easier, while the join-part would get longer, so I think I would not gain very much (if I am wrong, feel free to correct me here).

So is my approach solid, or am I missing something that might go horrible wrong in the future?

**orders-table:**

```
orderingsid productnumber   deliveryaddress billingaddress  thankyouletteradress
    1           70                  1           1                   1           
    2           80                  2           3                   3           
    3           90                  3           4                   5           
    4           100                 4           1                   4           
    5           110                 5           2                   2
```

**address-table**:

```
adressid    customername    street  zipcode location
    1           frank       "str a"     17      m   
    2           anton       "str b"     18      n   
    3           stefan      "str c"     19      o   
    4           tim         "str d"     20      p   
    5           alice       "str e"     21      q
```

Comment: if a given customer is "delivery" in one order and a "billing" in another, do you want it listed as the same customer?  if yes, then using your first method will give you big problems (if he moves for instance).

Comment: Design of a data structure should not be determined by how long it takes to write a particular sql statement. You should rather ask yourself which table structure supports your business processes better. Think about in which scenario it is easier to set up a new address, change or delete an existing one. You should also ask yourself what happens if you needed a 4th type of address as well.

Comment: @user1930608: No, the users should not be the same. What problem would arise, if for instance frank moved to street f? Wouldnt the orders-table simply contain an old order with the old street and a new order with the new street?

Comment: @Shadow: I'm not very experienced when it comes to knowing which structure supports my business process better. I am working for an elevator company, so our products wont move around so I thought, having only 1 address table might be simpler, but you are right. Especially when we need another address something might not be as easy. But as our project is rather small, I thought a smaller table might be better? My Professor once told me, not to develop things for the future that might or might not be needed. So I am a bit lost here what the "best" approach is, however best ist defined...

Comment: The problem is that we have absolutely no idea about your business processes, so any solutions we would suggest would be based on opinion, rather than experience. "Best" approach - as even yourself indicated - is also extremely opinion based, since every developer will have a different notion as to what best is.

Comment: What would happen if "frank" ordered an elevator, and then moved and ordered another elevator?Are you trying to store the address that the order was sent to or the address that the customer lives at?  if the former, than you don't really need to put it into a separate table.  If the latter, you want to avoid having the same information in more than one place.

Comment: @Shadow: I think I will stick with the standard approach. I've split up the adresses into their own tables, therefore the SQL-statement even gets a bit shorter and easier to read. The reason I've split them up is, that another developer does not need to understand my one table that contains all, but can see a clear separation. So "doing what everyone would usually do" might be the "best" approach here since it is the most clear one.

Comment: @user1930608: I've separated my tables now, since this approach seems to be more clear to an outside developer. Since it is also a more normalized database, it should not run into the problems you've described.